# Plot a table of ranges

Tags: plotting, graphics, equation-solving

I have table with values like:

```
t = {1.234 <= a <= 2.345, 3.42 <= a <= 5.67, ...}
```

and I want to plot this table, the `x axis` should be the number of element in table (first value, second value etc.) and the `y axis` should be values of `a` which satisfy the inequality

Comment: @Artes Hmm...so what is the conclusion? Maybe that only one answer was as good as I expected, and only 4 were a little help or steer on the right course?

Comment: @Artes I'm not expecting any help from you. If you want, you can answer my question. If you don't, it is also ok. First of all, I will accept any answer if I will read all answers and decide which was the most helpful and explained. Yo gave your answer two days ago, maybe I just think it wasn't an answer worth accepting. I am glad, that you posted your answer, but it just wasn't good for me, because it was not well explained and edited so many times, that I just stopped to read it. So I will not accept you answer, sorry.

Comment: You deleted your comment that my answer was what you were looking for. In general I don't answer such questions, nonetheless I wanted to provide some help rather extraordinarily because of the new year. It appears I shouldn't.

Comment: My answer was edited only two times, and only because you requested some more detailed explanation. I did it partially in a comment and providing another approach in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using pattern-replacement:

```
(* Generate some input *)
SeedRandom[1];
u := RandomReal[];
ranges = Table[u <= a <= u + 3, {i, 1, 10}]
(* test the patern replacement *)
ranges /. L_ <= a <= U_ -> {L, U}
(* plot *)
With[
 {pairs = ranges /. L_ <= a <= U_ -> {L, U}},
 ListPlot[{First /@ pairs, Last /@ pairs},
   Joined -> True, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]]
```

output:

```
{0.242992 <= a <= 3.05046, 0.32668 <= a <= 3.86396, 
 0.626079 <= a <= 3.56989, 0.0298104 <= a <= 3.24608, 
 0.198906 <= a <= 3.65168, 0.534017 <= a <= 3.33043, 
 0.599726 <= a <= 3.43771, 0.780776 <= a <= 3.04535, 
 0.907559 <= a <= 3.18661, 0.394221 <= a <= 3.60119}

{{0.242992, 3.05046}, {0.32668, 3.86396}, {0.626079, 
  3.56989}, {0.0298104, 3.24608}, {0.198906, 3.65168}, {0.534017, 
  3.33043}, {0.599726, 3.43771}, {0.780776, 3.04535}, {0.907559, 
  3.18661}, {0.394221, 3.60119}}
```

[image]

**Edit**. Actually the pattern replacement is not needed, this will do just as well:

```
ListPlot[{First /@ ranges, Last /@ ranges}, Joined -> True, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]
```

Comment: Your edit is nice! +1

Answer (score 7):

Let's exploit an obvious approach using `ParametricPlot`:

```
tab = { 1.234 <= a <= 2.345, 3.42 <= a <= 5.67, 2.13 <= a <= 5.39, 
        3.14 <= a <= 4.66, 1.33 <= a <= 3.77, 2.31 <= a <= 5.11   };
```

Now one can map a function over `tab`

```
i = 0;
tab1 = { ++i, First @ # + ( Last @ # - First @ #) t}& /@ tab;
```

or apply at the first level of `tab` another function:

```
i = 0;
tab1 = { ++i, #1 + (#3 - #1) t} & @@@ tab;
```

Most of *Mathematica* programmers prefer the latter approach, it is more concise and we expect it is more efficient (but in general it depends on various details of implementation, so it should be considered on a case by case basis).

```
ParametricPlot[ tab1, {t, 0, 1}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

We needn't define another list of data since the above can be evaluated inside `ParametricPlot`,  using different input e.g.:

```
tab3 = ((3 + 2Min @ # <= a <= 3 + 2 Max @ #& @ {Sin[#/3], -Sin[#/3]})& /@ Range[38]);
```

we could do this:

```
Block[{i = 0},
  ParametricPlot[{ ++i, #1 + (#3 - #1) #2} & @@@ tab3, {a, 0, 1}, 
                 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.008], Evaluated -> True]]
```

insted of unnecesary playing with `Block` we could simply exploit `Length` of `tab3` and `Transpose`:

```
ParametricPlot[ Transpose[{Range[Length[tab3]], #1 + (#3 - #1) #2 & @@@ tab3}], 
                {a, 0, 1}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.008], 
                Evaluated -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: In the first case we added `++i` which evaluates to `1, 2, ..., n` during subsequent steps. To understand the first approach use  `FullForm` on `tab` or on any of its elements. Then you'll understand why we needed `First` and `Last`.  In the second approach we used standard _Mathematica_ notation for pure functions (`#1`, `#3` denotes respectively the first and the third argument of oa function, if it applies to `1.234 <= a <= 2.345` `#1` will evaluate to `1.234` while `#3` to `2.345`). See documentation what is a pure function.

Answer (score 4):

A graphics approach:

```
tab = {1.234 <= a <= 2.345, 3.42 <= a <= 5.67, 2.13 <= a <= 5.39, 
   3.14 <= a <= 4.66, 1.33 <= a <= 3.77, 2.31 <= a <= 5.11};

Graphics[Line@MapIndexed[{{#2[[1]], #1[[1]]}, {#2[[1]], #1[[3]]}} &, tab], 
 Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {0, All}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### [StackedListPlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StackedListPlot.html)

```
SeedRandom[1]
t = (# <= y <= #2 & @@@ (Sort /@ RandomReal[100, {40, 2}]));

t // Short[#, 5]&
```

> {11.142 <= y <= 81.7389, 18.7803 <= y <= 78.9526, 6.57388 <= y <= 24.1361,<<34>>,
> 33.4215 <= y <= 83.3364, 69.4751 <= y <= 90.9209, 20.1479 <= y <= 85.104}

Get the lower series from  and the difference between the upper and lower series from `t`:

```
t2 = Transpose[{#, #3 -#} & @@@ t];

StackedListPlot[t2, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]
```

[image]